# intersectedObjects not working

Tags: javascript, three.js

I`m struggeling with this for a couple of days now and I finaly gave up and decided to ask you. I am trying to have a simple object detection and since inetersectScene was replaced with intersectObjects which is not recursive I am creating a new array where I store all objects I want to have the interaction with. I am trying that with pure mesh and with object3d as well and it is not working for both of them. Then I am passing my array to the intersectObjects function but the returned array is always empty.

Here is some code:

```
// Translate page coords to element coords

var offset = $(this.renderer.domElement).offset();

var eltx = pagex - offset.left;

var elty = pagey - offset.top;

// Translate client coords into viewport x,y

var vpx = (eltx / this.container.offsetWidth) * 2 - 1;

var vpy = -(elty / this.container.offsetHeight) * 2 + 1;


var vector = new THREE.Vector3(vpx, vpy, 0.5);

this.projector.unprojectVector(vector, this.camera);

var ray = new THREE.Ray(this.camera.position, 
vector.subSelf(this.camera.position).normalize());

//console.log(ray);

var intersects = ray.intersectObjects(this.intersectedList);

console.log(intersects.length);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not working because your camera is the child/grandchild of multiple objects, one of which has translation applied.

```
this.camera.parent.parent.position.y
```

returns -249.

So `this.camera.position` is not the true, world, camera position.

Try using `this.camera.matrixWorld.getPosition().clone()` instead.

Like this:

```
var cpos = this.camera.matrixWorld.getPosition().clone();
var ray = new THREE.Ray( cpos, vector.subSelf( cpos ).normalize() );
```

three.js r.53

Comment: So basicaly the camera.parent should be the scene? and if not - I cant have rotation... so that means i cant use controls? (OrbitControls)

Comment: I edited my answer. It may not be a three.js problem. See if you can get it working.

Comment: it is definately something with the camera position because when I changed it and started moving around intersectObjects began to retun some objects but my cursor was on random positions. Any other ideas how I can modify the camera? The other question is should I use the list I of objects I am building or the scene.children will do the work as intersectObjects' parameter? Really thank you for your time...

Comment: Sorry, but I've already spent a couple of hours with your code, and I just can't spend more. I hope you understand. I never got my arms around all of it. See if you can answer your questions by experimenting. Also, if you think there may be a problem when the camera is a child of a Control, then please make a simple jsfiddle example and file a bug report. My thinking at this point is that my answer above is correct.

Comment: i have a small question... since my camera.position is not my actual camera position I can get my real camera position from the world matrix but this gives me a vector with the position. how can I pass that to projector.unprojectVector since it is accepting camera as a second parameter which is actually not my real camera? so instead of camera can I pass just my actual camera position somehow?

Comment: If you look at the source code of `projector.unprojectVector()` you will see that it references `camera.matrixWorld`, so all should be OK passing in just `camera`. Like I said, if you think there is a bug, please make a simple live example.

Answer (score 0):

`intersectObjects` has a recursive flag:

```
var intersects = ray.intersectObjects(this.intersectedList, true);
```